# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle' not found in /var/www/znata.com/app/AppKernel.php on line 47

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

i followed [this](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/installation.html) doc to install SonataMediaBundle but i got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle' not found in /var/www/znata.com/app/AppKernel.php on line 47
```

After using the sonata command t generate the app:

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataMediaBundle
```

new directory was generated under:

```
apps/Application/Sonata/MediaBundle
```

everything was done but when i registred the generated application in my AppKernel.php i got that error.

```
public function registerbundles()
{
    return array(
        ...
        new Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle(),
        ...
    );
}
```

Have you any idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Can you describe exactly the path of your bundle?

Answer (score 9):

By default project root directory is not in the autoload path, only "src" dir.
You can use

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle
```

to generate bundle in the src or simple copy it to the src.

Answer (score 6):

After debug this problem, i found that the namspace Application is not registred.

In SF2.0, the documentation said that we should register this namespace like:

```
<?php
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    ...
    'Application'   => __DIR__,
    'Imagine'       => __DIR__.'/../vendor/imagine/lib',
    'Gaufrette'     => __DIR__.'/../vendor/gaufrette/src',
    'Buzz'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/buzz/lib',
    ...
));
```

but in SF2.1 they did talked about this.

So i registred the namespace Application in autoload.php and it works fine.

so, the autoload.php look like this:

```
<?php

// file: app/autoload.php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

//custom for Application
$loader->add("Application", __DIR__);


// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

With this new config everything is fine.But in SF2.0, they talked also about "Imagine", "Guffrette" and "Buzz" namespaces. So perhapes, when using them, we should register them also like Application namespace.

I hope that this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Using composer I did this in composer.json:

    `"autoload": {
        "psr-0": { 
            "": "src/", 
            "Application": "app/" 
        }
    },`

I added the mapping "Application": "app/".
And then run 
`composer update`

This generated extra autoloading needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. inside your `composer.json` file, have:

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "psr-4": {
           "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
           "Application\\": "src/Application"
       },
   }
   ```
2. do a simple:

   ```
   composer dump-autoload
   ```

   to re-generate the autoload files.

Comment: thanks perfect, but i prefer keeping bundle logic : `"Application\\": "src/Application" --> "Application\\Sonata\\UserBundle\\": "src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle"`

Answer (score 0):

```
new Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\MediaBundle(),
```

or

```
new Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\SonataMediaBundle(),
```

Answer (score 0):

As skonsoft mentioned, you need to load the namespaces in `autoload.php`. I had the same issue with FOQ.Elastica and resolved it by adding the following.

`$loader->add('FOQ', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles');`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use your app namespace prefix so the package falls under your namespace

`bin/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle --namespace_prefix=App`